# How to properly calculate percentage change in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

say from A1 to A2, A3 could be (A2-A1)/A1

however this fails if A1 is 0 so if the expression is wrapped around IFERROR it becomes IFERROR((A2-A1)/A1,1) so 0 to anything would be a 100% increase.

but now if A2 is also 0 this expression gives 100% when it should be 0%. is there any way around this?

Comment: Percentage change is undefined when the first value is zero. You could represent that by N/A for example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a nested `IF` instead of `IFERROR`:

```
=IF(A1=0,IF(A2=0,0,1),(A2-A1)/A1)
```